# change column data "variablah uniqueid" to "uniqueid of variablah" in mysql similar to excel's replace all

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a column "ProviderName" in table "main" that is populated thus:

```
Alaska Medicaid
Arizona Medicaid
Arkansas Medicaid
California Medicaid
Colorado Medicaid
```

and the list goes on...

I need to move it around to look like this:

```
Medicaid of Alaska
Medicaid of Arizona
Medicaid of Arkansas
Medicaid of California
Medicaid of Colorado
```

UPDATE:

Ok, with Quassnoi's command I get this:

**Before**

```
Alabama Medicaid
Alaska Medicaid
Arizona Medicaid (AHCCCS)
Arkansas Medicaid
California Medicaid
Colorado Medicaid
Colorado Medicare
Connecticut Medicaid
Delaware Medicaid
Florida Medicaid
Georgia Medicaid/Peachstate
Hawaii Medicaid
Idaho Medicaid
Illinois Medicaid
Indiana Medicaid 
Iowa Medicaid 
Kansas Medicaid
Kentucky Medicaid
Louisiana Medicaid
Maine Medicaid (MaineCare)
Maryland Medicaid
Massachusetts Medicare
Massachusetts Medicaid
Michigan Medicaid (CHAMPS)
```

**After**

```
Medicaid Alabama
Medicaid Alaska
(AHCCCS) Medicaid
Medicaid Arkansas
Medicaid California
Medicaid Colorado
Colorado Medicare
Medicaid Connecticut
Medicaid Delaware
Medicaid Florida
Medicaid/Peachstate Georgia
Medicaid Hawaii
Medicaid Idaho
Medicaid Illinois
 Medicaid
 Medicaid
Medicaid Kansas
Medicaid Kentucky
Medicaid Louisiana
(MaineCare) Medicaid
Medicaid Maryland
Massachusetts Medicare
Medicaid Massachusetts
(CHAMPS) Medicaid
```

I lost 5 states in this. Arizona, Michigan, and Maine fell off maybe because there was extra parenthesized text involved. Yet, Indiana and Iowa fell off and got indented without any extry text. Also, there is not "of" between Medicaid and the state name. How to perfect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE   mytable
SET      providername = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ProviderName, ' ', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ProviderName, ' ', -2), ' ', 1))
WHERE    providername REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+ Medicaid'
```

Comment: Please see my update to the original question above. This is going in the right direction.

Comment: I realize your answer would not have been a problem for the states with parenthesized text since my original question didn't contain that. Forgive me for that.

Comment: @Captain: is it a one-off task?

Comment: Yes, but I'm sure I'll use the framework of your command again for other mass edits. (I may have just said yes and no at the same time: "one-off" is new to my vocabulary).

Comment: I cleaned it (my columns) up and then ran your command and all is well. Thanks.